# IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/' explanation

Tags: python, json, file, directory, operating-system

I am getting this error from this code.

```
import os
import requests
import shutil


path = "/Users/mycode/Documents/API upload/"


api_endpoint = "xxxxxx"


files = {
    'file': open(p,'rb') for p in os.path.abspath(path)
}

for file in os.path.abspath(path):
    response = requests.post(url=api_endpoint, files=files)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.status_code)
        print("success!")
    else:
        print("did not work")
```

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'

^ what does this error mean? I tried googling it but still do not understand in my case. It has something to do with the paths but not sure why.

anything helps!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to upload (POST) all files from a specific directory. This is not the way to do it

Comment: yes! that is what i am trying to do. Any suggestions on other ways of doing it? would help a lot!

Comment: Well the first part is that the`path` starts with `/` which in the `files` dict is the first thing looped over so in `files` you're doing `'file': open('/', 'rb')`. You can't open any directory, namely `'/'` here. Regardless even if you gave the `path` defined here, it would still be a directory not files within the directory. Perhaps you want to get the paths to the files in there. Use something like `os.walk` or `glob.glob` to get the files you need.

Comment: thanks! ill try and use os.walk. I have tried using os.listdir(path) but it only works in the directory. I am trying to upload the files from the folder!

Comment: @Albert You mean by `os.path.abspath(path)`? It wouldn't raise such error.

Comment: where would i use os.walk?

Comment: @MYousefi I actually made an error in my code to test this. You are right - my bad. However, I can't help wondering why one would pass an absolute path to abspath() in the first place

Comment: No reason. Any path given by some `root` directory traversal function would be relative to its `root`.  It will be an absolute path when joined with the `root`. Wouldn't even matter if it was given in absolute. Joining multiple absolute paths with path module would result in a path relative to the last absolute path in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for p in os.path.abspath(path)
```

doesn't do what you think it does.

It does **not** iterate over all files in a given directory. Use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) for that. You can combine the directory path and the filename inside the directory using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). [The pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) has an IMHO simpler to use / higher level interface to all of this.

What your code does is iterate over all characters in the string returned by `os.path.abspath(path)`. And the first character is `/`. Which you then try to open as a file. And that doesn't work, because `/` is a directory.

Comment: when i use os.listdir for that, it only works within the directory. I am trying to access the files from a folder in my computer

Comment: Sounds like you need [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) or [the slash operator of pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators)

Comment: I think it is os.path.join but os.path.join brings me back to the error of IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'

Comment: At this point it's anyone's guess what your code looks like.

Comment: The `for file in os.path.abspath(path):` line has the same problem, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider doing this in chunks because if your directory contents are very large, you could run out of file descriptors.

Something like this should work:

```
from requests import post
from glob import glob
from os.path import join, isfile

DIR = '/Users/mycode/Documents/API upload/'
CHUNK = 10
API_ENDPOINT = '...'

filelist = [filename for filename in glob(join(DIR, '*')) if isfile(filename)]

for idx in range(0, len(filelist), CHUNK):
    files = [('file', open(fn, 'rb')) for fn in filelist[idx:idx+CHUNK]]
    post(API_ENDPOINT, files=files).raise_for_status()
    for _, fd in files:
        fd.close()
```

**Note:**

For improved efficiency you should consider multithreading for this

Comment: Not opening all files at the same time is a good suggestion. Doing it in chunks seems very much like overkill for most use cases. And suggesting multithreading to an apparent beginner is like handing out shotguns at kindergarten.